# Movie DataBase problem (probably with Api)

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi guys I've got a problem that for a couple of days it made me crazy.
So, I'm doing a Movie APP in Android Studio (adapting then to a Social Network but it's not important for now) and I was following the tutorial about a certain "Master Code" but naturally he gives to me a basic answer for my problems. My problem is: I've followed his tutorial but at the moment when I'm testing the visibility of the films in my Application it happens nothing. I see that he can see the list of the film in the API following the LogCat in Android Studio but in my case, I've got no results. But it compiles correctly but at the same time, I cannot see the results. I'm just trying to insert the API inside my App and with a button when I click it, I'll see the list of the film inside the API. Maybe I've got previously some errors about the Api.. because I cannot understand how to apply this kind of code :

```
//that's the MovieApi Interface on the next Screenshot

package com.example.movieapp.utils;

import com.example.movieapp.response.MovieSearchResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;

import retrofit2.http.GET;

import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface MovieApi {

    //Search for movies
    //https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={api_key}&query=Jack+Reacher

    @GET("search/movie")
    Call<MovieSearchResponse> searchMovie(

            @Query("HERE I'VE PUTTED MY APIKEY") String key, <-- I've changed this parameter
            @Query("query") String query, <-- I leave it default
            @Query("page") int page <-- I leave it default
    );

}
```

And this one is connected with this (that it was the "MainActivity" where I want to obtain this result I guess)
[image]

I hope all of you could help me because I don't want to copy, I want to understand some think about this project.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET("search/movie")
  Call<MovieSearchResponse> searchMovie(

      @Query("api_key") String key,
      @Query("query") String query,
      @Query("page") int page
  );
```

Comment: So, what do you want to see to me? Maybe I guess that I've should leave also apy_key parameter default? Maybe for this reason I don't have any output?

Comment: Hey man I tested API in postman with my key and it works, now what shoul I do? I saw that when I put "api_key" in the "(...)" field the logCat shows me a lot of errors about google and others e not shows me the list of films inside the Api list..

Comment: I solved the problem and now compile.. but there's something wrong in that because I cannot see the list of films. I know that the Api was installed well because before it gives to me 1 film (the end of the list but it's always a film) but now when I insert the card view and list of item to see Api Film as a List in my Application.. I cannot see anything. Some advice?

Comment: I can't help you if you don't post your code

Comment: I think that the problem is here : https://pastebin.com/LEmQfuhX
or there : https://pastebin.com/9QmHts9i
or even there : https://pastebin.com/yxYJh0Ry. I'm sorry if I sent you so much code.. but I can't find the error and compiler tells me it'all right when I cannot see the Api

Comment: I want to see them like a list created with the Recycler View and through this gives to me the list of the film contained in the Apis of Movie DB

Comment: did you see recyclerview show only one film or nothing

Comment: No but this fact happened before I started to implement the Recycler View and elements to see Api film on a List in Android Studio. Before, I used the Textview just to have an output and it gives me the last film of the filmlist.. but other film it didn't happears. With the Recycler view I cannot see neither the single film and I don't know why.. what it wrong..

Comment: seem nothing wrong, Log.v("Tag", "onChanged: " + movieModel.getTitle()); print anything?

Comment: No Man, it gives me nothing..I mean nothing about the output of the movies in the log. It showes me a lot of process in opening mode, extracting or some errors not about my code. Neither in the log it gives to me the list of the film.. But when i put the Textview.. It showes me the last film on the list. Maybe i have other files that contain errors? If you want I can show you but I hope to not disturb. And when i search "TAG" to find my list of movies it returns me an error about a font. This : "e/minikin: add font failed to create font /system/fonts/notosanstagbanwa-regular.ttf"

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s04UgcG3 - https://pastebin.com/suS2DQM0 - https://pastebin.com/7Cu1N74L - https://pastebin.com/aQFSbppH - https://pastebin.com/nqP6F6fq - https://pastebin.com/Lig90Le9 - https://pastebin.com/cFFyWLzF - https://pastebin.com/3ZiwdLjx - https://pastebin.com/BYrAFqaV That's all I have

Comment: I don't know where it is this error that cannot make me see the list of films. But i hope you can help me because i'm lost. Literally. Other these file there is the manifest but i don't think that it was wrong. Idem for the gradle.

Comment: You handled livedata wrong, follow this example https://github.com/learntodroid/MVVM-REST-API

Comment: And I have to delete all the project? I mean, I should delete every part about the live Data? because I don't want to do the search field but only shows me the list of films.. as a Top rated or the home like Netflix just to make an example.

Comment: You dont have to delete all, just see how to use livedata with retrofit and viewmodel. Search also same as get list film